# Activity closes when trying to asyncronously connect to twitter

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I have been trying to program a twitter client for Android (using twitter4j). So far the idea is to have a simple GUI, and if there is not a file with the OAuth token in the SD Card, connect to the Twitter API using AsyncTask, get the URL for the authorization and open the default browser. However, the browser never runs. Depending on the different modifications I have made trying to fix this, either the Activity starts normally but the browser never starts or the Activity crashes. I have come to a point of a a little of frustation and confussion. Can someone point out what's wrong with my code?

```
public class StatusActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "StatusActivity";
EditText editText;
Button updateButton;
File oauthfile = null;
public Context context = getApplicationContext();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);

    Log.d(TAG, "started");
    // Find views
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); //
    updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);

    oauthfile = new File("sdcard/auth_file.txt");

    //Check if the file with the keys exist
    if (oauthfile.exists()==false){
        Log.d(TAG, "file not created");
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "file not created.",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        new Authorization(context).execute();

    }


}

public void openBrowser (View v){
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "onclick");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.status, menu);
    return true;
    }
}

class Authorization extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, String>{
String url = null;
private Context context;

 Authorization(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }



public void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       Toast.makeText(context, "Invoke onPreExecute()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
      }


@Override
public String doInBackground(String... params) {
    ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
//I have eliminated the keys from the question :)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    Twitter OAuthTwitter = new TwitterFactory(configBuilder.build()).getInstance();
    RequestToken requestToken = null;
    AccessToken accessToken = null;     
    do{
        try {
            requestToken = OAuthTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
            url = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
        } 
        catch (TwitterException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    while (accessToken==null);
    return url;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Opening browser.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS, Uri.parse(url));
    context.startActivity(browserIntent);
}
}
```

I know that at least checks if the file for the tokens exists because the toast "file not created" appears, and that the activity is able to run the browser if I press the button. The app has permissions to write in the SD card and use the Internet. Thanks in advance.

Logcat Trace:

```
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.versec.pardinus/com.versec.pardinus.StatusActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.versec.pardinus.StatusActivity.<init>(StatusActivity.java:30)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
03-28 19:02:32.816: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You can use this.context=context or as you are using asynctask as inner class you can take context as field in the class, but it doesn' look good.. this.context = context.getApplicationContext();

Comment: It will be better if you could provide crash report. i.e logcat trace

Comment: Please provide crash reports

Comment: @Pragnani Yeah...I think I don't understand very well what Context is for. I have been looking at a lot of examples from the internet so maybe some stuff is weird.

Comment: @Versec What is line no 30 in StatusActivity?

Comment: @Pragnani public Context context = getApplicationContext();. User Rich says it crash comes from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is causing your crash.

```
public Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

You're not even using it when you need it, so you can just get rid of this line.

Btw, something else I noticed while looking at your code is this:

```
oauthfile = new File("sdcard/auth_file.txt");
```

Don't take the "sdcard/" path for granted.  Use this instead:

```
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File oauthfile = new File(dir, "auth_file.txt");
```

Comment: Well, now it doesn't crash at the start and shows the Invoke onPreExecute() Toast. However it still doesn't open the browser, Apparently it gets stuck on the do while loop for some reason I'm trying to figure out. About the sd card, I knew writing "sdcard/" is not a good practice, I just didn't bother to change it.

Comment: your termination condition is when the oauthtoken is no longer null, but I don't see you setting this variable in your loop.  Sounds like an infinite loop

Comment: Indeed. I changed it to while(url==null), and changed also Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); and added the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the browserIntent. Now it works. Thanks to you and the other whoe helped, this is the right answer.